# Наследование и сериализация

Tags: c#, сериализация, json.net

Имеется базовый класс `AudioObject`, от которого наследуются два класса: `Audio` и `AudioUser`. Также имеем класс `AudioList`, в котором есть поле `List<AudioObject>`. В этом поле может храниться список объектов смешанных типов: `Audio` и `AudioUser`.

```
public class AudioObject
{
}

public class Audio : AudioObject
{
    public uint id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}

public class AudioUser : AudioObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class AudioList
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public List<AudioObject> list { get; set; }
}
```

Попытаемся сериализовать и десириализовать объкт `AudioList`:

```
AudioList list = new AudioList();
list.count = 1;
list.list = new List<AudioObject> { new Audio { id = 1, title = "Test"} };

string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);

AudioList newList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AudioList>(serialized);
Audio audio = newList.list[0] as Audio;
```

Сериализация происходит успешно, но вот десериализация возвращает нулевые объекты из списка `List<AudioObject>`.

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Вы б указали, в какой JSON у вас сериализовалось.

Comment: Вот результат сериализации:

"{"count":1,"list":[{"id":1,"title":"Test"}]}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `null` for `audio` because items in deserialized list are instances of base `AudioObject` class - according to `List<>` declaration. Add type information to [de]serialization:

```
AudioList list = new AudioList();
list.count = 1;
list.list = new List<AudioObject> { new Audio { id = 1, title = "Test"} };

JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() {
  TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.All 
};
string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, settings);

AudioList newList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AudioList>(serialized, settings);
Audio audio = newList.list[0] as Audio;
```

Comment: Probably you forgot that you should answer in Russian there :D

Answer (score 3):

Используйте настройку [`TypeNameHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm), чтобы информация о типах сохранялась в JSON:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
    // или All для того, чтобы десериализовать не только объекты дочерних типов,
    // но и коллекции разных типов (IList/IEnumerable)
};
string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, settings);

AudioList newList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AudioList>(serialized, settings);
Audio audio = newList.list[0] as Audio; // != null
```

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало