# Десериализация абстрактного класса в JSON в C#

Tags: c#, json, десериализация

Имеется абстрактный класс `Worker`, который имеет 2 наследника `Hourly` и `Fixed`, в которых просто переопределяется абстрактный метод. Также имеется класс `Organization`, содержащий `List<Worker>`:

```
public class Organization
{
    public List<Worker> Workers { get; set; } = new List<Worker>();
}
```

В классе `Program` создается объект: `Organization company = new Organization();`. В ходе работы программы `company.Workers` заполняется экземплярами классов `Hourly` и `Fixed`.
Нужно организовать сериализацию в `workers.json` и десериализацию из `workers.json` в тот же самый `company.Workers`. Я использую Newtonsoft.

Сериализация в следующем виде работает без проблем:

```
using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText("workers.json"))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Serialize(file, company.Workers);
}
```

А вот при десериализации происходит следующая ошибка: `Could not create an instance of type ConsoleApplication2.Worker. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated.`. Я пробовал 2 разных способа:

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText("workers.json")) 
{ 
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer(); 
company.Workers = (List<Worker>)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(List<Worker>)); 
}
```

и

```
using (FileStream fstream = File.OpenRead("workers.json")) 
{ 
byte[] array = new byte[fstream.Length]; 
fstream.Read(array, 0, array.Length); 
string file = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(array); 
company.Workers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Worker>>(file); 
}
```

В обоих случаях происходит указанная выше ошибка.
Я пробовал искать решение на разных ресурсах, но не нашел ничего, что бы мне подошло.

**upd**
Проблема заключалась в том, что как при сериализации, таки и при десериализации нужно было создать `var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto, Formatting = Formatting.Indented };`. При сериализации вместо `JsonSerializer();` используем `JsonSerializer.Create(settings);`, а при десериализации передаем `settings` вторым параметром вместе с `file`.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1065490/%d0%94%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-json-net-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bc/1065501#1065501 ?

Comment: Попробовал сделать так, выдает ошибку конвертации: `using (FileStream fstream = File.OpenRead("workers.json")) 
{ 
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All }; 
byte[] array = new byte[fstream.Length]; 
fstream.Read(array, 0, array.Length); 
string file = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(array); 
var x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(file, settings); 
company.Workers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Worker>>(x, settings); 
}`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Наследование и сериализация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413545/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: Попробовал следующее, ошибок нет, но заполнение листа не происходит.  `JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All }; 
string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(company.Workers, settings); 
company.Workers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Worker>>(serialized, settings);`. В том вопросе описывается решение для случая, когда лист заполняется одним дочерним классом, а не обоими сразу как в моем случае.

Comment: Значит вы делаете что-то не так. Делайте самодостаточный пример, который покажет эту проблему, ибо в простом [примере](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UtQcLj) все работает как надо.

Comment: На основе вашего примера [сделал то, что получается у меня](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k0HJQV)

Comment: @NoName, и сохранять и читать нужно с `TypeNameHandling`  https://dotnetfiddle.net/M9ug9b

Comment: @Exploding Kitten, благодарю! Проблема решилась.